# How to install gert package without Internet access

Tags: r, devtools, gert

I'm trying to install package devtools from source as I don't have Internet access on the RStudio server. So far I've been failing to install dependence package gert - during installation it tries to run a script (attached below) which requires Internet access. I downloaded and unpacked those files (https://r-lib.github.io/gert/libgit2-1.1.0.x86_64_linux.tar.gz;https://r-lib.github.io/gert/libgit2-1.1.0.x86_64_legacy-linux.tar.gz) but I have no idea how to use it to finally install gert package. Can somebody help me with overcoming this obstacle?

```
IS_MUSL=$(ldd --version 2>&1 | grep musl)
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "$IS_MUSL" ]; then
echo "Do not use static libgit2 on MUSL C"
else
URL="https://r-lib.github.io/gert/libgit2-1.1.0.x86_64_linux.tar.gz"
OLDOPENSSL=$("${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript" -e 'cat(openssl::openssl_config()$version)' | grep "OpenSSL 1.0")
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "$OLDOPENSSL" ]; then
URL="https://r-lib.github.io/gert/libgit2-1.1.0.x86_64_legacy-linux.tar.gz"
fi
"${R_HOME}/bin/R" -q -e "curl::curl_download('$URL','bundle.tar.gz')"
tar xzf bundle.tar.gz && rm -f bundle.tar.gz
PKG_CFLAGS="-DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I${PWD}/libgit2/include"
PKG_LIBS="-L${PWD}/libgit2/lib -lgit2 -lrt -lpthread -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpcre -lz"
HAVE_STATIC_LIBGIT2=TRUE
fi
```

Comment: This question is ot answered after 2 years although it was viewed 266 times. This is a problem because devtools package depends on gert (via usethis). Therefore if my computer is not connected to the internet, I can not develop packages. To make it clear, the problem is not about getting the archive, it is about the installation process itself. During installation of gert, the packages tries to open a connection with github:
`Error in curl::curl_download("https://r-lib.github.io/gert/get-libgit2-linux.sh",  : 
  Failed to connect to r-lib.github.io port 443: Connection timed out`

Answer (score 0):

Download the package source of `gert`,

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/gert_1.3.2.tar.gz

Then select in RStudio,

Tools > Install packages > Install from Package Archives

Select the downloaded `.tar.gz` file.

Comment: It's excatly what I did as I mentioned in my post that I'm trying to install package from source which implies downloading .tar.gz file and then installing it with tools/or install.package(). It tries to connect Internet anyway so it doesn't work.